# How to manually remove pip on windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, package-managers

I am using Python 3.4 (I know it is deprecated, but don't have the power to upgrade version).

I had trouble installing some packages because of a old version of pip (1.5.6 I guess), so I went all

```
pip install -m pip
```

To upgrade version and... it broke.

Unfortunately, it installed the latest, incompatible 20.0.2 version, which now raises a RuntimeError asking me for Python 3.5, and now I'm stuck. I can't upgrade Python, I can't downgrade pip because it will not allow me to.

How can I remove or downgrade pip manually?

Comment: Have you tried 'pip install pip==<Version>' to install specific version of pip.

Comment: @AnupamChaplot yeah but it obviously raises and error due to python version being too old. I have already resolved, posting an answer right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easier that it seems. You can actually use the same `get-pip.py` script used to install pip the first time.

The script, available [here](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py), actually contains a full working version of pip to be used to bootstrap the installation. This version is fully working, so it can be used to install packages with a different version that the one contained.

To solve, just use https://bootstrap.pypa.io/3.4/get-pip.py to recover a version of `get-pip.py` compatible with my python environment (note the 3.4 in the link) and run

```
get-pip.py pip==19.1.1
```

This removes the newer python version and installs the older one, restoring the usual functionalities.